# weakSelf and strongSelf in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

In case when there are many references to weakSelf inside block, it is recommended to create its strong version. The code looks like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.theBlock = ^{
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

    [strongSelf doSomething];
    [strongSelf doSomethingElse];
};
```

What I am concerned with is this line in the above code:

```
__strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

Isn't it erroneous when we write `typeof(self)`? Is referencing `self` allowed here?

In the tutorials they sometimes write:

```
__strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

Both versions are used 50/50. Are the both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it erroneous when we write typeof(self)? Is referencing self allowed here?

(A) No. (B) yes

`typeof` is an (Objective-)C language extension which in a declaration (here you are declaring `strongSelf`) is handled by the compiler as *compile time* - there is no use of `typeof` in the resulting compiled code. A primary use of `typeof` is in `#define` macros which enables a single macro to be expanded to work on different types; again such macro expansion occurs at compile time.

In your case you are constructing a block in an instance method, in abstract your code will look something like:

```
@implementation SomeClass {

- (someReturnType) someInstanceMethod {

... ^{ typeof(self) strongSelf = weakself; ... } ...

} }
```

Here `typeof(self)` is effectively just a "shorthand" for `SomeClass`. The use of `self` is processed at compile time and no reference to runtime object referenced by `self` is captured.

> Both versions are used 50/50. Are the both correct?

The are identical in meaning. The rules of ARC state that if no qualifier is present then `__strong` is assumed, so one version relies on this and the other makes the qualifier explicit.

HTH